# How to have background hosted service run only in 1 Pod?

Tags: c#, .net, background-process, azure-aks

I have a .Net Core Web API application that I am running in AKS in multiple pods. It also includes a background task (Hosted Service);

For specific reasons, this task needs to run inside the same API application because it contains processing / reflection that requires the same class / methods inside. It checks a SQL Database for some records and process it.

How would I approach this so if I have multiple pods, there is no duplicate processing going on?

Comment: You could use a lock that prevents more than 1 instance of being able to run the task. See https://github.com/Ibis-Software/Ibis.MutexLeaderElection for a library that can be used. As soon as the instance running the background job is stopped another one will take over.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I would have marked it as answer as it helped point me in the right direction for the patterns, but it is comment.